# Nodes, children, append new element

Tags: dart

Given this code:

```dart
Element elem  = new Element.html("<p>This is a paragraph.</p>");

document.body.append(elem);
document.body.children.add(elem);
document.body.nodes.add(elem);
```

The results are the same when I `add` to `body.children` or to `body.nodes`. What is the difference between the two? Which is better?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll try to explain it easily.

Let's assume this HTML snippet:

```html
<div>
  Hey!
  <span>How is it going?</span>
</div>
```

Now, the thing is that the [`children`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_html/Element.html#children) property comes from the `Element` class. It returns a list of other `Element` objects:

```dart
List<Element> children
```

So, elements can have children who are elements, and so forth.

But then we have the [`nodes`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_html/Node.html#nodes) property, which comes from the `Node` class. It returns a list of other `Node` objects:

```dart
List<Node> nodes
```

So, nodes can have child nodes who are nodes themselves too.

The question you should ask is what's the difference between a node and an element?

Let me add some comments to our previous HTML snippet:

```html
<div> <!-- Element -->
  Hey! <!-- Node -->
  <span> <!-- Element -->
    How is it going? <!-- Node -->
  </span>
</div>
```

Remember, `Element` extends `Node`, which means that `<div>` and `<span>` are not only elements, but also nodes! Everything is a node in HTML. In fact, even comments `<!-- foo -->` are nodes!

When you access the [`nodes`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_html/Node.html#nodes) property, you will retrieve a list of nodes, basically a list of everything under it, including HTML comments and text.

Retriving the [`nodes`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_html/Node.html#nodes) for the `<div>` tag above would return one `Node` ("hey!") and one `Element` (`<span>`). However, retrieving the [`children`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_html/Element.html#children) property would only return a list with a single `Element` (`<span>`).

So, `nodes` literally contains everything, including elements, text nodes, comments, document types and more.

To answer your question now:

```dart
 document.body.append(elem);
 document.body.children.add(elem);
```

These two are the same, the first is just a wrapper for convenience.

When you *add* to `nodes` or `children`, there isn't really much difference. However, if you retrieve the property, the result can differ. I would generally advise you to use `children` because the results are more what you would expect.

Implementation wise, there are little differences as Kyrra mentioned, but nothing too concerning.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Kai's answer is much better.

ORIGINAL:
`document.body.append(elem)` is just a wrapper for `document.body.children.add(elem)`.

As well, `document.body.elements` is just a wrapper for `document.body.children`.

`.nodes` and `.children` use different underlying classes to implement their functionality.  Functionality wise, these 2 children provided the same set of List functions.  Both are missing implementations for: `sort`, `setRange`, `removeRange`, `insertRange`, and the setter for `length`.  Though, the 3 range functions may be implemented in the future.

The important difference between nodes and children is that `nodes` uses **lazy initialization** for accessing the children.  Specifically, its' constructor just does:

```
_ChildNodeListLazy(this._this);
```

While the constructor for `children` does:

```
_ChildrenElementList._wrap(Element element)
  : _childElements = element.$dom_children,
    _element = element;
```

The `children` class calls the $dom_children immediately at construction, which makes sure the children from the DOM are accessible.  The `nodes` class does not use any of the native $dom_* calls until you do something (like adding an item).

Beyond that, `nodes` and `children` seem to be the same.

As far as which is better, it depends on your use case.  If you will be saving a reference to the child list but not accessing it right away, `nodes` is better.  But neither is all that efficient right now as the getter for `nodes` and `children` both create new instances of the wrapper classes every time you call the getter (calling `body.children` creates a new instance of the _ChildrenElementList class).  Because of this, if you are doing a lot of subsequent calls on the children of body, I'd recommend using the `..` notation.

```
document.body.children
    ..add(a)
    ..add(b)
    ..add(c)
    ..add(d);
```

You can see more information about the cascade operator `..` in the [language tour](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch02.html#classes).